# The drush command 'variable-get' could not be executed

Tags: drush, configuration

Command variable-get requires Drupal core version 6 or 7 to run.
The drush command 'variable-get' could not be executed.

drush st
 Drupal version                  :  8.7.3
 Site URI                        :  http://default

How do I get to change variables with a fresh install 
** I did not upgrade - I'm a newbie to Drupal

```
I have looked at the drush/commands/core/variable.drush.inc 
I can see that 
    'core' => array(6,7),
    'core' => array(6,7),
    'core' => array(6,7),
but changing any of it is just breaking it further and weirder ;-)
```

any suggestion ? 
I like to be able to update user's attribute email password from the CLI

Comment: " variable-get requires Drupal core version 6 or 7 to run." You're running on D8 so it won't work. Look up the equivalent Drush config set command for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and informative answer Shawn